# Select lines using ranges in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to select lines visually.

Usually I'd `SHIFT-V` and select with `j` and `k` to highlight the lines.

How do I do it using a colon-range command? e.g. `:10,12<?>` to select lines 10 - 12 and enter visual mode with that selection. What should I insert for `<?>` here?

I'm sure it's easy but I don't know what keywords to web-search/browse help for.

Comment: How about `10GV12G`?

Answer (score 25):

Like jw013 says, you can use the vim movements:

```
10GV12G
10GV2j
```

If you still want a range command:

```
command! -range Vis call setpos('.', [0,<line1>,0,0]) |
                    \ exe "normal V" |
                    \ call setpos('.', [0,<line2>,0,0])
:10,12Vis
```

For details:

```
:help command-range
:help setpos(
```

Comment: command! -range Vis normal! <line1>GV<line2>G